# I can't handle mysqli connect exception, because php always shows error

Tags: php, exception, mysqli

My problem is that I'm trying to make exception-handling, so if my page can not connect to the mysql database, it should write an error message that I made. It partly works, I can see my error message, BUT I also see two additional php errors.

Here is a picture:
[image: error] 
Here is the code:

```
if(!mysqli_connect($server, $user, $passw, $db)) //line 12
    $_SESSION['page'] = "conn_err";
```

I have tested with echo, the variables have values, they are not empty or null!
The variables are test values, so they are wrong, to test if the exception handling works. Btw., I'm on localhost, and I'm using wampserver.

Soo... I want if only that one error message would be visible I made.

I tried to solve the problem with try-catch, also tried with a connection variable and an if statement, but nothing worked. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Edit:
I forgot the versions...

PHP version: 5.5.12
Apache version: 2.4.9
MySQL version: 5.6.17

Comment: Disable `display_errors` in production environment. Also remove or disable the xdebug extension in production environment.

Comment: Just as Charlotte said, if you want to disable the error reporting you can do so in your php.ini for your WAMP server. Here's a guide: [Disable PHP Error Reporting](http://tahirtaous.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-hodedisable-php-errors-in-wamp.html)

Comment: Hmm, but if I disable error reporting, then no error will be displayed.. I want to see errors, except this time, when I test the connection...